# ¿Se pueden iterar llamadas a AJAX dentro de un ciclo for?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo este bloque que llama unas funciones mediante *AJAX*:

```
var datos = new FormData();
datos.append("idComedor", idComedor);

$.ajax({

    url: "ajax/menus.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(respuesta) {
        console.log(respuesta)

        for (let i = 0; i < respuesta.length; i++) {

            var datos3 = new FormData();
            var idIngrediente = respuesta[i]["id_ingrediente"]
            datos3.append("idIngrediente", idIngrediente);

            $.ajax({

                url: "ajax/menus.ajax.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: datos3,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(respuesta2) {
                    console.log(respuesta2)
                },
                error: function(respuesta2){
                    console.log("Error al entrar a AJAX.")
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Y en el archivo `ajax/menu.ajax.php` tengo esto:

```
class AjaxViandas{
    /* Mostrar vianda comedor */

    public $idComedor;

    public function ajaxMostrarViandaComedor(){

        $item = "id";
        $valor = $this->idComedor;

        $respuesta = ControladorViandas::ctrMostrarViandas($item, $valor);

        $respuesta2 = ModeloViandas::mdlObtenerIngredientes($respuesta["id"]);

        echo json_encode($respuesta2);
    }

    /* Traer nombre ingrediente */

    public $idIngrediente;

    public function ajaxMostrarIngrediente(){

        $item = "id";
        $valor = $this->idIngrediente;

        $respuesta = ControladorIngredientes::ctrMostrarIngredientes($item, $valor);

        echo json_encode($respuesta);
    }
}

/* Objeto mostrar vianda comedor */
if(isset($_POST["idComedor"])){

    $mostrarComedor = new AjaxViandas();
    $mostrarComedor -> idComedor = $_POST["idComedor"];
    $mostrarComedor -> ajaxMostrarViandaComedor();
}

/* Objeto traer datos ingrediente */
if(isset($_POST["idIngrediente"])){

    $mostrarIngrediente = new AjaxViandas();
    $mostrarIngrediente -> idIngrediente = $_POST["idIngrediente"];
    $mostrarIngrediente -> ajaxMostrarIngrediente();
}
```

La cosa es que el primer *AJAX* imprime correctamente el `console.log(respuesta)`, en cambio el segundo, que se encuentra dentro del ciclo `for`, no entra, pasa por esta línea de error:

```
console.log("Error al entrar a AJAX.")
```

La variable `idIngrediente` se carga y se pasa correctamente, y según lo que veo ambos bloques de código están escritos prácticamente iguales, por eso no entiendo qué es lo que sucede.

Comment: Esta traza: `console.log("error al entrar a ajax")` la tienes dentro del callback de success de la primera llamada, no en el callback de error de la segunda, por lo que no te sirve para determinar si ha habido un error o no. Además, es normal que se ejecute, porque la siguiente instrucción a ejecutarse después de la llamada ajax es justamente la que haya a continuación, no salta automáticamente al callback de success/error.

Comment: mmm creo que estas equivocado (y solo lo creo porque definitivamente yo estoy equivocado). Si seguis bien el codigo vas a ver que ese console log esta totalmente fuera del ajax, pero dentro del ciclo for. No esta dentro del success ni del error, esta por fuera de ``$.ajax({})``

Comment: Si, está dentro del success de la primera llamada a Ajax.

Comment: Ahh entiendo, claro, todo esta dentro del success del primer ajax, y si, es al pedo ponerla ahi porque no va a reconocer si hay un error o no. Ahi edite el codigo agregando el bloque de error, puse el console adentro, y lo imprime, es decir, no entra al 2do ajax

Comment: @ordago ahora si esta donde corresponde, verdad? Sigue imprimiendo "Error al entrar a ajax"

Comment: Sí, así estaría mejor. Si ese console.log de error lo cambias por esto: `console.log("error al entrar a ajax: " + respuesta2);` puedes ver que error te está devolviendo el servidor para ayudar a determinar el problema.

Comment: @ordago si lo pongo como vos decis imprime ``error al antrar a ajax [object Object]``, y solo pongo ``console.log(respuesta2)`` imprime ``{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}``

Comment: Abriendo el objeto me encuentro con un texto que me dice "SOS UN BOLUDO, NO IMPORTASTE ingredientes.controlador"... me azotare solo un rato, gracias

Comment: Ahi se solucionó, me faltaba importar el modelo y el controlador de clientes... Deberia eliminar la pregunta porque nada tiene que ver con lo que me pasaba, o la dejo asi? Muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Bueno por lo menos llegaste a la solución :-) Lo mejor es que pongas una respuesta rápida indicando cual era el problema y como lo has resuelto y marcándola como aceptada.

Comment: Lo que estas haciendo es una pésima forma de programación. Poner una llamada ajax en el succes de otro ajax es terrible. Imagina que la 1ra llamada se tarda, y luego tienes que hacer una segunda llamada que también se tarda. Que sensación le darias al usuario? Que la aplicación no funciona. Ajax se usa para dar sensación y performance similar a una aplicación de escritorio y con esa forma de programar vas encontra de todo ello.Es mejor juntar todos los datos del cliente que necesites procesar en el server y enviarlos en una sola petición ajax procesar todo en el server y devolver una respuesta

Comment: Es mi segundo proyecto con estas tecnologias, apenas tengo meses trabajando con esto. Gracias, es dificil tratar de trabajar solo con esto, ya que nadie te dice "mejor que hacer esto, es hacer esto otro". Como veras la primer llamada ajax recupera datos, que los utiliza la segunda, y todavia me falta una tercera... Lo ideal entonces seria, en la primer llamada, en lugar de devolver esa respuesta, es operar con la base de datos, traer todos los datos en esa unica respuesta, y asi traer todo con la unica llamada a ajax?

Comment: Hola @Mani hay casos en que el proceso en el servidor puede ser muy largo y necesite partirse mostrando avances en el cliente (como ejemplo el batch de activación/actualización de módulos usado por [Drupal] versión 6x) cuando tengas un rato me buscas en el chat y te explico como hacerlo con ajax. (No posteo una respuesta aquí porque podría no ser pertinente)

Comment: @Mani Si tu ventana va a cargar varios cosas de base de datos, por ejemplo, catalogos, esa es la mejor forma, porque en general los catalogos son finitos y dependiendo del catalogo no pasan de 10,100, 1000, o tal vez 5000 registros. Si vas a tratar de obtener cantidades mas grandes como millones de registros hay formas de hacerlo, por ejemplo, la paginación, donde solo traes una pequeña muestra de esos millones y asi tienes mejor peformance y solo traes muestras de esa cantidad enorme en cada pagina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad el problema era que no estaba importando el `controlador` ni el `modelo` de los ingredientes, cuando estaba llamando a sus funciones.

El error se pudo visualizar cuando agregué el bloque:

```
error: function(respuesta2){
    console.log(respuesta2)
}
```

A la llamada *AJAX* que tenía el problema.

Una vez visto el objeto en consola, lo expandí y tenia una propiedad llamada `responsetext` donde se encontraba el texto.

> `<br />↵<b>Fatal error</b>`:  Uncaught Error: Class `'ModeloIngredientes'` not found in...`

Claramente me indicaba que nunca había importado el archivo con la clase `ModeloIngredientes`.